# How to scale width svg with css or jQuery

Tags: svg, scale

When this photo is converted to svg. it is not responsive for all devices
For example, in a resolution of 4K or lower, its width should be changed, but the height should not be changed.

[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHFl5.png)

This Image For Full HD and To 4K resolution scale width

thanks

Comment: I don't think svg allows you to change aspect ratio dependent on viewing resolution, in fact I think it is totally resolution-independent as that is the central idea.

Comment: Do you know better?  Malcolm McLean

Comment: Can you please post add the markup of the "converted" svg and explain how exactly you want it to behave? It should be possible to achieve this with CSS media queries (tough browser support is a different story).

Comment: I want to change the height of its width

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve].  If you want us to help us fix your SVG, then we need to see it.